# Was ist damit gemeint: "Das schleckt keine Geiss weg!"

Tags: meaning, etymology, idiom, swiss-german

Unsere Politiker überbieten sich mit blumigen Phrasen!
Es vergeht keine Parlamentssitzung, in der nicht am Schluss seines Votums
seinen Worten damit Nachdruck verleihen will: "Das schleckt keine Geiss weg!"

Was aber damit genau gemeint ist, weiss wohl keiner so genau.

Ich frage nicht nach einer möglichen Übersetzung, sondern versuche zu ergründen, was der ursprüngliche Sinn dieser (sprich)wörtlichen Aussage ist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88741/discussion-on-question-by-albrecht-hugli-was-ist-damit-gemeint-das-schleckt-ke).

Comment: Der Inhalt aller Kommentare ist im oben verlinkten Chat aufrufbar damit er von dort in ein Edit oder eine Antwort kopiert werden kann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was "damit gemeint ist" scheint mir etwas anderes zu sein als "wo das herkommt".

Die folgende Überlegung ist zwar nur volksetymologisch, und anscheinend eine eher private Theorie, aber sie klingt mir ziemlich naheliegend für den zu vermutenden Deutungsrahmen:

> Ein [Leckstein](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leckstein) ist ursprünglich ein natürliches Produkt aus einem Salzbergwerk und dient der Versorgung der Tiere mit Salz. Es handelt sich dabei um einen Block aus Mineralsalz, entweder direkt gebrochen, gegossen oder gepresst und eventuell mit nichtmineralischen Zusätzen versetzt (sogenanntes Viehsalz). Insbesondere für Wildtiere werden diese im Fachhandel angebotenen Steine an ausgesuchten Stellen ausgebracht, den sogenannten Lecken, Salzlecken oder auch Sulzen.

Immerhin würde ein Vergleich zwischen Granit und Leckstein unter Ziegenzungen jedenfalls die [Wiktionary Erklärung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/das_schleckt_keine_Gei%C3%9F_weg) stützen:

> schweizerisch; Bestätigung einer Aussage: daran ist nicht zu rütteln, das ist unabänderlich, das ist so und nicht anders, dagegen ist nichts zu machen

Daher meine Vermutung, dass etwas, auf das sich “Das schleckt keine Geiss weg!” bezieht, eher 'das hier ist so dauerhaft und fest wie Felsgestein' gemeint sein könnte, wenn im Vergleich sonst die gierigen Geissen etwas ähnlich aussehendes in kurzer Zeit weggeschleckt bekommen?

Comment: macht jetzt kaum mehr Sinn als der Vergleich zur kahlen Wiese. Nochmal mit nüchternem Blick betrachtet glaube ich bald, es ist ein Mondegreen aus "schlägt". Widder sind als Rammböcke bekannt. In der That wäre Geiß als Bezeichnung für einen militärischen Rammbock vorstellbar. Ziegen sind immerhin störrisch und werden hinlänglich auch eingezäunt.

Comment: @vectory Widder und Geiß sind zwei vollständig unterschiedliche Tierarten (Schaf und Ziege).

Comment: @tofro perhaps chosen only for metric reasons? It [my mistake] doesn't make a difference because the -bock is agnostic about the species, but I'm not sure wether the allusion to the Bock is etymological, cp. e.g. *Prellbock* vs *Bogen*.

Comment: Ich habe auch an das Salz gedacht und gemeint, es gehe darum:  Salz ist essenziell. Ohne Salz ist das Essen fade. Ohne Salz verderben Lebensmittel. Das schleckt keine Geiss weg. Aber ... was macht das für einen Sinn?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Nimm einen Leckstein und einen Granitstein, ritze auf beide ein eben beschlossenes Gesetz ein. Ein schlechtes Gesetz auf Salz ist schnell verschleckt. Ein gutes kommt auf den Granit, und die Geiss müht sich nach Kräften, ohne Erfolg. Das wäre ein Vergleich zur Beständigkeit zweier unterschiedlicher Gütearten, zweier unterschiedlicher "Steine"?

Comment: Wehe der Geiss, dia das wegschlecken will!

Comment: Wir haben zwar keine Beweise, aber der Gedanke mit dem Leckstein - verbunden mit der Redewendung "in Stein gehauen" - wie in Granit gehauen - macht für mich auf einmal am meisten Sinn. Nur: Ob das die Politiker selbst bedenken???

Answer (score 4):

Ich hab das in Deutschland noch nie gehört, aber [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/das_schleckt_keine_Gei%C3%9F_weg) weiß was es bedeutet und hat auch ein deutsches und österreichisches Synonym.

> Bedeutungen: schweizerisch; Bestätigung einer Aussage: daran ist nicht zu rütteln, das ist unabänderlich, das ist so und nicht anders, dagegen
>   ist nichts zu machen
>
> Synonyme: da beißt die Maus keinen Faden ab, österreichisch: da fährt die Eisenbahn drüber

Die Synonyme habe ich allerdings auch noch nie im Alltag gehört.

Zur Herkunft des schweizer Ausspruchs habe ich online nichts gefunden. Für das deutsche Synonym gibt es gleich mehrere [Theorien zur Herkunft](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/da_bei%C3%9Ft_die_Maus_keinen_Faden_ab):

> 1. Am häufigsten findet sich ein Bezug zur Fabel „Der Löwe und das Mäuschen“. Dort rettet die Maus einen in einem Netz gefangenen Löwen, indem sie das Netz durchbeißt. Wenn die Maus keinen Faden abgebissen hätte, wäre der Löwe in Gefangenschaft geblieben und hätte nichts dagegen machen können.
> 2. Eine andere Deutung geht davon aus, dass ein Schneider seinem Kunden versicherte, dass dessen Stoff bei ihm gut aufgehoben sei, und keine Maus einen Faden abbeißt.
> 3. Nach einer Legende reizte eine Maus die heilige Gertrud von Nivelles (unter anderem die Schutzpatronin gegen Mäuse- und Rattenplagen) beim Spinnen dadurch, dass sie mehrmals den Faden abbiss. Der Namenstag der heiligen Gertrud ist der 17. März, der im Bauernkalender den Beginn der Arbeit auf dem Feld ankündigt (und damit das Ende der winterlichen Handarbeiten wie Spinnen, Weben). Wer jedoch die Spindel nicht aus der Hand legt, dem beißt eine Maus den Faden ab. Es gibt einige Sprichwörter, die einen Zusammenhang zwischen Gertrud mit der Maus und der unabänderlichen Abfolge der Jahreszeiten herstellen, z. B. „Gertrud hört mit Spinnen auf, sonst läuft die Maus den Faden auf und beißt ihn ab.“ (österreichisches Sprichwort)
> 4. Bei einer früher verbreiteten Art von Mausefallen muss die Maus einen Faden abbeißen, um an den Köder zu kommen. Das löst eine durch den Faden gespannte Feder, eine angehängte Drahtschlinge schnellt nach oben und tötet die Maus. Fehlt der Köder, wird die Maus auch den Faden nicht abbeißen.
> 5. Früher wurden Lebensmittel im Keller mit einem Faden an die Decke gehängt, damit diese nicht von den Mäusen gefressen wurden. An die an der Decke hängenden Lebensmittel kommt eine Maus nicht heran und kann auch den Faden nicht abbeißen, damit diese herunterfallen. Somit sind die Lebensmittel sicher vor der Maus.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maus_Nagetier) nennt auch die Herkunfstheorie Nr. 2.

Comment: ja, daran ist nichts zu meckern!  
Es erklärt aber nicht, wie die Geiss bzw. Maus ins Bundeshaus kommt!  (Auch wenn die Bauern dort nach Käse Kuhmist riechen ...)

Comment: @Iris die Maus ist hier relativ nebensächlich, und die mir bekannte (unbelegte und daher zweifelhafte Theorie) oben in den Kommentaren erwähnte Theorie hast du auch nicht erwähnt.

Comment: Da wiktionary für "Geiß" auch die märchenhafte Deutung Muttertier (vgl. En *nanny goat*) nennt, kommt der Spruch "Da muss eine alte Frau lange für Stricken" in Erinnerung, der in übertreibung auch bedeuten mag, *das wird nie was*, daher *da ist nichts dran zu rütteln*, wenngleich ich dies nie in derartiger Übertreibung gehört habe. Den Geißen Spruch habe ich jedoch eingangs ohne Kontext so verstanden.

Comment: @Vectory, als ich meine Antwort gepostet hatte, war von Herkunft noch keine Rede. Das habe ich dann, so gut wie möglich, ergänzt. Ich hatte extra nicht die Herkunftstheorien aus den Kommentaren übernommen, da ich den Kommentatoren die Chance lassen wollte, das selbst als Antwort zu posten.

Comment: @Vectory Dem Idiom "Da muss eine alte Frau lange dafür stricken" die Bedeutung "das wird nie was" zuzuordnen, finde ich etwas sehr weit hergeholt. Das heißt ganz einfach "das ist viel".

Answer (score 4):

> Ich frage nicht nach einer möglichen Übersetzung, sondern versuche zu ergründen, was der ursprüngliche Sinn dieser (sprich)wörtlichen Aussage ist.

Ich beziehe mich hier auf [@Hans Jakobs ursprünglichen Kommentar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48672050#48672050) und poste das mal als Antwort:

> > Die Geiss (Ziege) "pflückt" Kräuter und Gräser, indem sie sie mit ihrer rauen Zunge ergreift und in den Mund zieht; Kraftfutter und ähnliche gekörnte Nahrung leckt/schaufelt sie ebenfalls mit der herausgestreckten Zunge auf. Weiterhin sind Ziegen dafür bekannt, ganze Landstriche kahl zu fressen, wenn man sie lässt.
> >     Wenn jetzt aber etwas so beschaffen ist, ***dass keine Geiss es aufschleckt***, dann muss es entweder so fest stehen, dass die Ziege es nicht schafft es abzureißen/aufzunehmen, oder vielleicht auch so unangenehm dass es sogar der gefräßigen, wenig wählerischen Ziege nicht schmeckt.

Comment: Ich habe zwar gemeint, es gehe um das Salz, aber eine Umfrage in meinem Bekanntenkreis ergibt für mich, dass du auf der richtigen Spur bist. Was aber will  das nun im übertragenen Sinn heissen?

Comment: @Albrecht Wie gesagt, es beschreibt den ***quantitativen*** Aspekt eines Problems IMO. Es lässt sich nicht so einfach _wegwischen_.

Comment: das kann genauso der qualitative Aspekt sein. Ich habe es immer so gedeutet: “und was ich hier gesagt habe, ist so richtig und wichtig, das schleckt keine Geiss weg!” Ja, das wäre dann zu gross für einzelne Geiss.  Dann wurde ich gestern Abend verunsichert durch Freunde, die meinten, es sei auf die Argumente der politischen Gegner bezogen: “Was ihr da erzählt, ist so ein grosser Stuss, das schleckt keine Geiss weg!” Möglicherweise haben alle  Recht...

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli _"Was ihr da erzählt, ist so ein grosser Stuss, das schleckt keine Geiss weg!”_ Das deutet in die richtige Richtung IMO. Zum Ursprung dieses Sprichworts kann ich leider nichts Verlässliches beitragen (ey Oida ;-) ).

Comment: Ich will das jetzt nicht noch als eigen Antwort posten und mich mit fremden Federn schmücken. Für mich ist der Fall klar, Die Frage ist hiermit gelöst! “Ich möchte feststellen, was ich hier vertrete, das steht so sicher und eindeutig fest ... das schleckt keine (noch so gefrässige) Geiss weg!”

Answer (score 3):

Das ist keine besonders blumige Ausdrucksweise, sondern einfach eine geläufige Redensart im Südwesten, um das Gesagte zu bekräftigen.

"Das könnt ihr nicht wegdiskutieren" "So ist es nun mal" "Daran
kommt ihr nicht vorbei."

Das Gesagte steht so fest, dass noch nicht einmal die Ziege (die ansonsten alles wegfrisst, was aus der Erde ragt) es wegschlecken kann.

Comment: Kurz, einleuchtend und überzeugend! Aha, ich habe schon eine ähnliche Antwort angenommen ...